# Windows equivalent of perl modules required (not available in activestate ppm) such as file::finder

Tags: perl, module, activestate

I'm attempting to import code written in linux into eclipse's perl plugin 'epic', and have installed activestate perl in windows. Most of the modules have an activestate equivalent, but some of them I can't find in ppm. Does anyone know how I can get the following modules so that the code can compile?

- File::Finder
- Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Utility
- Sybase::CTlib
- Sybase::DBlib
- Sybase::Xfer
- Template
- Template::Constants
- DBD::Sybase
- File::Rsync
- PerlIO/gzip

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best option is probably to remove Active Perl and replace it with [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/).  Because the Strawberry Perl installation includes a compiler, you are able to install most CPAN modules using the standard CPAN shell.

Comment: Hi Grant, thanks for the ideas. I ended up installing the MinGW package which seems to compile packages on active perl. Still, there are a few packages that won't yet compile.

Answer (score 1):

Trouchelle to the rescue!

http://trouchelle.com/perl/ppmrepview.pl?l=Template-Toolkit&v=10

The other modules cannot be built because of test failures or missing libraries.

Comment: I wish I'd looked at this before attempting to compile them myself :( This repository of ppm modules had most if not all of the ones I was able to compile.

Answer (score 1):

i downloaded the File:finder module from cpan and was able to install successfully in the windows.
Only difference is we need to use nmake instead of make.

Comment: I'll give this a try soon. I noticed on trouchelle that file::finder is listed as ok on perl 5.8 but failed testing on 5.10. Hopefully doing things with nmake manually will be ok. Hmm....

Answer (score -1):

You can download perl modules from https://metacpan.org/ and then compile the same in windows.

Comment: ...as long as the distribution doesn't have an XS component.

Comment: why is that Ether? Can't windows compile using dmake.exe or whatever it's called?

Comment: Because of binary compatibility! You need to have and use the same compiler that Activestate used to compile their perl.

Comment: PerlIO::gzip has this problem when compiling with mingw. I assume this is where compiling with strawberry perl comes in handy. I don't suppose anyone knows what compiler I should use to get my modules to work with ActivePerl 5.10.1 Build 1007?